# Public URL for localhost app, to use with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tunnel

I am developing an app on rails 3.1 that will be using the [facebook registration plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/). I am following [this tutorial](http://veerasundaravel.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/facebook-registration-plugin-in-rails/) to do the integration. However, while i am developing my application on localhost:3000, when i create my facebook application on facebook, I need to enter a public URL for the application.

Currently i am using this [awesome gem (localtunnel)](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) to get me a public URL and it works fine. However the problem is that the URL it provides is just temporary until i restart localtunnel. Is there a way I can get a constant URL (any ugly url will do) so that I can continue development with facebook while facebook can also access my localhost:3000 through a public URL?

Comment: how do others here make their localhost development publicly accessible? any other tips on how to get a constant public url to your localhost?

Comment: this may help, http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/ lots of routers support this built-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have an problem setting the Facebook app url to `localhost:3000`. Have you tried that? It works fine as long as you're testing it on a computer with the rails server running.

If that doesn't work, you might consider using a no-ip technology: [www.no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/) (it's free for a subdomain)

Comment: putting in localhost:3000 gives this error when trying to use fb

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Comment: definitely try no-ip.com then. It gives you a permanent public url that always points to your development machine.

Answer (score 1):

Localtunnel: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Answer (score 1):

Hi' if it's still relevnt constant URL - https://ngrok.com/ 
works great

Answer (score 0):

you can use lvh.me:3000 as an alternate to localhost.

http://veerasundaravel.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/localhost-alternates-for-subdomain/

Answer (score -2):

Install the [heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) gem and upload your app there.

Comment: in that case I will need to push it to heroku every single time i make a change during development and need to check it with facebook. isn't there a way like localtunnel where i can keep developing on my machine but just have a non changing public url?